# View or Hide a dropdownlist in my razor view using helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an object named `Visit` and i defined the following `helper method` (“CanBeEdited”) to specify if users can edit the object `Status` property or not:-

```
public partial class Visit 
    {
        public bool CanBeEdited(string username)
        {return (((DoctorID != null) && (DoctorID.ToUpper().Equals(username.ToUpper()))) && (StatusID == 5));       }     }}
```

Then i have specified to show or hide certain `dropdownlist` on my `Edit` view depending on weather the `CanBeEdited` helper method returns true or false (if it returns true then the user can view and edit the `Status dropdownlist`, and if it returns false then the view will render an `@Html.HiddenFor` representing the old status value).

My edit view which includes the helper method looks as following:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Visit</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("DoctorID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorID)
        </div>

        @{
       if (Model.CanBeEdited(Context.User.Identity.Name))
       {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("StatusID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusID)
        </div>
       }
       else
       {
       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StatusID)}
}
        <p>
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VisitTypeID)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VisitID)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PatientID)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.timestamp)

        <input type="submit" value="Create" />

        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

To be honest it is the first time i implement such as case,, **so is my approach sound valid ???,, or it have some weaknesses i am unaware of ??**. As i need to implemented similar cases all around my web application...

*Baring in mind that i am also checking for the CanBeEdited on the action methods..*

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Updated:-**
My post action method look as follow:-

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Visit visit)
        {
            if (!(visit.Editable(User.Identity.Name)))
            {
                return View("NotFound");
            }
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    repository.UpdateVisit(visit);
                    repository.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                var clientValues = (Visit)entry.Entity;

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit "
                + "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The "
                + "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database "
                + "have been displayed. If you still want to edit this record, click "
                + "the Save button again. Otherwise click the Back to List hyperlink.");
                //   patient.timestamp = databaseValues.timestamp;
            }

            catch (DataException)
            {
                //Log the error (add a variable name after Exception)
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator.");
            }
            ViewBag.DoctorID = new SelectList(Membership.GetAllUsers(), "Username", "Username", visit.DoctorID);
            ViewBag.StatusID = new SelectList(db.VisitStatus, "StatusID", "Description", visit.StatusID);
            ViewBag.VisitTypeID = new SelectList(db.VisitTypes, "VisitTypeID", "Description", visit.VisitTypeID);
            return View(visit);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel adding that in the View is  a good idea. I would like to have My ViewModel to hold a property of boolean type to determine that it is editable or not. The value of that you can set in your controller after checking the relevant permissions.

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
  public bool IsEditable { set;get;}
  //other relevant properties
}
```

and controller action

```
public ActionResult GetProduct()
{
  ProductViewModel objVM=new ProductViewModel();
  objVm.IsEditable=CheckPermissions();

}
private bool CheckPermissions()
{
  //Check the conditions and return true or false;
}
```

So view will be clean like ths

```
@if (Model.IsEditable)
{
  //Markup for editable region
}
```

Comment: but i do not think that using viewmodel in my case will work with my current implemnetation for the Post Edit action method. (i update my original question to include the code for the action method )

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it sounds valid enough.

UPDATE: removed irrelevant commentary, and edited to indicate a primary concern.

Now, taking a closer look, especially with the controller action, I strongly recommend that you eliminate the hidden fields (except the one that you need to re-load the record from your back end).

A savvy user can tamper with the hidden form data (all the form data) and your controller action will happily send it all back to the server.

In reality, you should post back only the fields that are permitted to be changed, rehydrate the record from the back end, and transfer the "editable" fields to the fresh copy. This also comes closer to addressing concurrent edit and stale record issues.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, actually the helper method is defined inside the object model class (in my case the Visit partial class) ,, and i am reusing the helper method on my views and controller action methods..

Comment: But... I would probably recommend against exposing the status field in a hidden field, which opens it up for form hacking. I mean, if they can't edit it, you probably don't need it in the form post, right?

Comment: but since i am passing an Object to my edit action method ,, then if i got not add the Status in a hidden field then the value will be null..

Comment: Not really,,, if the helper method returns true then the user should be able to edit the status ....

Comment: I modified my answer to address my concern about the hidden fields.

Comment: but how can i get the values from the database for the fields that i do not want the user to be able to edit,, since i am passing a new Object to my post action method ,, so in this case i can only use the values that are in the hidden fields...

Comment: It looks like you are performing an update action. Which means you loaded *something* before showing the form int the first place. If that's true, you'd load the data in the same way.

Comment: The update method is just used to mark the object as modified ,, here is how the UpdateVisit method looks like:-                                                           public void UpdatePatient(Patient p)
            {
                entities.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
               
            }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10568/discussion-between-brightgarden-and-john-g)