# How can i retrieve the object properties values from the database, in my action method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following Post Edit action method, which include a [Bind] list to restrict the properties that the model binder will bind:-

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Bind(Include="Note,DoctorID,VisitID,StatusID")] Visit visit) 
        {
if ((visit.EditableByAssingedDoctor(User.Identity.Name)) || (visit.EditableByCreatedBy(User.Identity.Name)))
            {  try
                {if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    { entities.Entry(visit).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        repository.Save();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");   } }
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {   var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                    var clientValues = (Visit)entry.Entity;
//code goes here
```

But since the Visit Object contains other properties that are not included in the bind list,, so how i can retrieve the current values for the Visit object properties from the database.
Hint:- I am using entity framework with database first approach.
BR

**UPDATED:-**
HERE IS THE GET EDIT action method:-

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {


            Visit visit = repository.GetVisit(id);
            if ((visit.EditableByAssingedDoctor(User.Identity.Name)) || (visit.EditableByCreatedBy(User.Identity.Name)))
            {

                ViewBag.DoctorID = new SelectList(Membership.GetAllUsers(), "Username", "Username", visit.DoctorID);
                ViewBag.StatusID = new SelectList(repository.FindAllVisitStatus(), "StatusID", "Description", visit.StatusID);

                return View(visit);
            }
            else { return View("NotFound");}
            }
```

Comment: i provide the HTTPGet action method..

Comment: Regarding VisitID it is already included in the Bind list.

Comment: Excellent! So then, in your post method, just do repository.GetVisit(visit.VisitId) and do the same check to see if it is editable before doing the update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; but retriving the object using the GetVisit(visit.VisitId) method will not raise the DbUpdateConcurrencyException -if the time stamp value was changed- because raising the DbUpdateConcurrencyException require passing the object as a parameter to the action method, and not by getting the object from the database using the object ID. THIS IS EXACTLY MY PROBLEM.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only the Note is editable, except sometimes the Status is editable as well? Based on [your other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10326538/1284283). I'm going out on a limb here since I don't know what your HTTPGet method looks like, and I'm rusty in EF.

I'm excluding the necessary checks, try/catch, etc...

```
var dbVisit = repository.GetVisit(visit.VisitId);
dbVisit.Note = visit.Note; // if this is permissible
if (dbVisit.IsEditable(...)){
     ... whatever is permissible here ...
}
repository.UpdateVisit(dbVisit); // possibly inside the if clause above
... etc ...
```

Comment: i provide the HTTPGet action method.. Regarding your approach i think that it will not raise the DbUpdateConcurrencyException exception to check for any concurrent access,, because raising the DbUpdateConcurrencyException -if the time stamp value was changed- require passing the object as a parameter to the action method, and not by getting the object using the object ID.